# calculate the avg of Option Int with scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm new to scala and I have a listbuffer in a map with this structure :     `ListBuffer(Note(test@gmail.com,Some(2)), Note(test@gmail.com,Some(3)))`

I want to calculate the avg of (Some(2),Some(3))
when i calculate the sum i get this error `Overloaded method value [+] cannot be applied to  (Any)`

```
var sum = 0
  for (note <- notes)
          sum += note.note.getOrElse("existe")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `note` property as `Option[Int]`. When you call `getOrElse(String)` compiler figure out result type as `Any`, the closest superclass of `Int` and `String`. As you know, `Any` doesn't have `+` method.

You may refactor your code in following way:

```
val numbers = notes.flatMap(_.note) // or notes.map(_.note.getOrElse(0)) if you want to consider empty notes

numbers.sum / numbers.length
```

Comment: Be careful with this solution to avoid `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` when `numbers.length == 0`, i.e. when there are no notes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foldLeft` to calculate the sum in a single parse. Where as the `flatMap` and then `sum` method take two parses of the list.

```
val sum = notes.foldLeft(0)({ case (acc, note) => acc + note.note.getOrElse(0) })
```

Also... how are you defining the avg in your case,

```
// lets say you have this list of notes
val notes = ListBuffer(Note("test@gmail.com", Some(2)), Note("test@gmail.com", Some(3)), Note("test.gmail.com", None))

// Now what is supposed to be your avg
// Do you want to consider a None as 0 or do you want to ignore it
// is it -> (3 + 2 + 0) / 3 = 5 / 3
// or is it -> (3 + 2) / 2 = 5 / 2

// If you want to consider a None as 0 then,
val (sum, count) = notes.foldLeft((0, 0))({
  case ((acc, count), note) => {
    note.note.map(i => (i + acc, count + 1)).getOrElse((acc, count + 1))
  }
})
val avg = sum / count

// if you want to ignore all None then,
val (sum, count) = notes.foldLeft((0, 0))({
  case ((acc, count), note) => {
    note.note.map(i => (i + acc, count + 1)).getOrElse((acc, count))
  }
})
val avg = sum / count
```